# How can I run a script when 1 of my 2 submit buttons within 1 form is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hi I have 2 submit buttons within one form.  The script below works to help prevent empty fields from being submitted by sending an alert msg to the user.  However I only need it to run with one of my two submit buttons is clicked.  So in other words if one button a if clicked it would submit the form with or without blank fields, and the other button would run the script below and not allow the form to be submitted with blank fields.  Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('form').on('submit', function () {
        var thisForm = $(this);
        var thisAlert = thisForm.data('alert');
        var canSubmit = true;
        thisForm.find('[data-alert]').each(function(i) {
            var thisInput = $(this);
            if ( !$.trim(thisInput.val()) ) {
                thisAlert += '\n' + thisInput.data('alert');
                canSubmit = false;
            };
        });
        if( !canSubmit ) {
            alert( thisAlert );
            return false;
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Include your script inside function. eg. function formWithEmpty(){ //ur script } and another function for other script. Call the function onclick of button.

Comment: You asked a very similar question 5 hours ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268612/how-to-apply-javascript-to-only-1-of-2-form-submit-buttons-within-1-form/29269301#29269301
I included a similar answer on both questions that accomplishes what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wiring up to the form submit event, wire up to the click event of the button that you want to validate with. Returning true from a click event will allow the submit to occur, and false will block it.

Comment: I get what you mean but how can I do this?

Comment: @Anthony C., there are a few examples of how to do that in the answers to this question, including my answer. Also, see the answers when you asked the exact same question a while ago. You have a lot of people who have already given you the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have one form and two submit buttons which, by default, will both submit the form.  To prevent one button from submitting, add a click handler that both prevents the default submit action and does whatever else you want that button to do.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" value="something" />
    <input id="submit1" type="submit" value="send" />
    <input id="submit2" type="submit" value="ignore" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#submit2').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Form will not be submitted
    // Do whatever you need to do when this button is clicked
});


$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var thisForm = $(this);
    var thisAlert = thisForm.data('alert');
    var canSubmit = true;
    thisForm.find('[data-alert]').each(function(i) {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        if ( !$.trim(thisInput.val()) ) {
            thisAlert += '\n' + thisInput.data('alert');
            canSubmit = false;
        };
    });
    if( !canSubmit ) {
        alert( thisAlert );
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Demo**  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/dqqfLxav/

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding the click event and adding classes to the submit buttons. So you know which button click will submit the form accordingly.

```
$('form button').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('.submit-without-validation')) { 
     $('form').submit();
  }

  if($(this).hasClass('.submit-with-validation')) { 
     //Do your validation and then submit
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many answered that you can use to achieve what you want. And you can try this one also. Here is some explanation. Basically, you need can use html5 data attribute to set the value to differentiate both button. When the button was clicked, you can check the value using condition as following code :

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" value="" id="name"/>
  <input type="submit" class="btn_submit" value="Submit validate" data-valid="yes"/>
  <input type="submit" class="btn_submit" value="Submit without validate" data-valid="no"/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data_valid = $(this).data('valid');    
    if(data_valid == "yes")
    { 
         // doing your stuff here for validation like example below
         var input = $('#name').val();
         if(input=="")
         {
             alert('required');
             return;
         }        
         // After the validation process finish, submit the form 
         $('form').submit();  
    }
    else
    {
        // submit without validation
        $('form').submit();            
    }    
});
```